# remove leading 0's in each row read from csv file in python. The format of a string is 012_0056_01. The output I need is 12_56_1

Tags: python, csv

I tried to use slicing but it only works for first part in a string.

```
with open('output.csv', 'r') as fin, open("C:/edit.csv", "w") as fout:
    c_reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter =',')
    writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter = ',', lineterminator = '\n')
    writer.writerow(headers)
    next(c_reader)
    row = next(c_reader)

    for row in c_reader:
        if(row[0][0]=='0'):
            row[0] = row[0][1:]
```

csv format data

```
key          key_name
012_0056_01  0120056_Name
```

Comment: split on `_` then map the resulting list to `int` and join back up with `_` as the seperator. Can you show some input data and where this conversion is needed in the above code.

Comment: this is string example 012_0056_01 i need it to be 12_56_1

Answer (score 1):

Short answer

```
'_'.join([str(int(n)) for n in row[0].split('_')])
```

Breaking it down

1. Split separate your string into the needed components

   `yourString.split('_')`
2. For each component, convert it into an int to remove the padding 0 and then convert it back to a string

   `str(int(component))`
3. Join the bits back together

   `'_'.join(bits)`

Comment: My bad, I meant row[0] for your case. You can only split a string. I edited my answer to match your code

Answer (score 0):

You could simply split the string by underscore and use `lstrip` to remove leading zeros. The rejoin using `join`.

```
>>> row = ['012_0056_01', 'other', 'other']
>>> '_'.join(n.lstrip('0') or '0' for n in row[0].split('_'))
'12_56_1'
```

This would avoid needing to do the conversion to `int` and back to `str`.

Note also to avoid stripping the sole 0 in the event the value was zero we can use.

```
n.lstrip('0') or '0'
```

Which will use the value `'0'` in the event `lstrip` returns an empty string.

When using csv with commas as delimiter, you can omit the `delimiter =','` argument as comma is the default delimiter.

Comment: doesn't like the split attribute for this list.

Comment: for every row in a csv file

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions for this:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("^0+", "", re.sub("_0+", "_", '012_0056_01'))
'12_56_1'
```

This replaces all consecutive zeroes at the start of the line, and following an underscore, with nothing.

Note that this will turn `00_0123_000_0456` into `_123__456` so, if you want to preserve those lone zeros, you can instead use:

```
>>> re.sub("^0+([^_])", "\\1", re.sub("_0+([^_])", "_\\1", '00_0123_000_0456'))
'0_123_0_456'
```

It's similar to the first example but replaces the pattern "consecutive zeros followed by something that isn't an underscore" with that "something".

Comment: for some reason its not working for every row first column.

Comment: @user3713579, it works perfectly on the sample data you gave. If you have some sample data where it isn't working, you should add that to the question (or, at a minimum, as a comment *including* the data).

Comment: sample data will be in the following  csv format
key                    key_name 
012_0056_01    012_Name   

and i have about 100 rows of data